# Firestore is not a function in Vue CLI application

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import config from './config'

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const firestore = firebaseApp.firestore()
```

I've been battling this for the past 24hrs, I got solutions to import the firebase/firestore, but still none seems to work for me.

```
init.js?9adc:10 Uncaught TypeError: firebaseApp.firestore is not a function
at eval (init.js?9adc:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (renderer.js:1309)
at __webpack_require__ (renderer.js:680)
at fn (renderer.js:90)
at eval (199:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (renderer.js:2035)
at __webpack_require__ (renderer.js:680)
at fn (renderer.js:90)
at eval (CustomersTable.vue?2194:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (renderer.js:2022)
```

Comment: What version of the client SDK are you using?

Comment: 4.6.0 Eventually, I was even able to use firestore, but i needed to refer to firebase from the node_modules folder like this "../../../../node_modules/firebase". Hope this is not going to affect build, because it is an electron app

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save @firebase/firestore
```

fixed this for me. It broke somewhere between firebase versions 4.5.0 and 4.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

To access the [firebase service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#use_firebase_services),

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import config from './config'

export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

Comment: This also didn't work..  i needed to refer to firebase from the node_modules folder like this "../../../../node_modules/firebase". But I dont know if this has any adverse effect